# Flutter: Change button color on TextField focus

Tags: flutter, focus, textfield

I have a text field and a separate button, I want to change the button's color when the text field focuses.

Naively, I would like to write: `FlatButton(..., backgroundColor: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.green)`. This, of course, does not work as the Button doesn't get notified about the focus change. Alternatively, I tried to add a `Listener` to `myFocusNode`, but if I try to call `setState` inside it in order to rebuild the button, the text field loses it's focus again.

I modified the sample code from the respective [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus) to illustrate, you can copy the code below and paste and run to see what I mean. How can i make the button turn red when clicking the text field?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Text Field Focus',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

// Define a custom Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Define the focus node. To manage the lifecycle, create the FocusNode in
  // the initState method, and clean it up in the dispose method.
  FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    myFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text Field Focus'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // The first text field is focused on as soon as the app starts.
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            // The second text field is focused on when a user taps the
            // FloatingActionButton.
            TextField(
              focusNode: myFocusNode,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // When the button is pressed,
        // give focus to the text field using myFocusNode.
        onPressed: () => myFocusNode.requestFocus(),
        tooltip: 'Focus Second Text Field',
        backgroundColor: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
        child: Icon(Icons.edit),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @rgissi, Have yoou checked the below solution, let me know in case of concern

Comment: Hi Ravindra,
Thank you for answering, and sorry for being slow. My development work was interrupted and I'll now resume and comment on your answer.

Comment: Ok , let me know in case of concern...And if the answer is workable for you then please accept it as useful for the future users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the below code , i have use the **`Focus`** widget for it, it has the **`onFocusChange`** which will indicate the `TextField` is selected or not

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutterlearningapp/colors.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool isTextFiledFocus = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Demo",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Focus(
                child: TextFormField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input 1"),
                ),
                onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                  setState(() {
                    isTextFiledFocus = hasFocus;
                  });
                },
              ),

              TextFormField(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input 1"),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: isTextFiledFocus ? Colors.pink : Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Ok"),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("I am clicked");
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And check the below output of it
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ravindra! This does indeed solve the problem, and using the `Focus` widget is very elegant.
Unfortunately, it creates a problem for me (but apparently not for you): On focus, the keyboard and the cursor disappear because I call `setState` inside `onFocusChange`... :-( Any idea how to solve this, maybe?

Comment: Alright, the keyboard problem was something different and is now solved as well: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20042 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help you man!!! Keep happy coding..please upvote it also

Answer (score 3):

`myFocusNode.requestFocus();` inside setState? 
Ps. Yep it worked for me

```
myFocusNode = FocusNode();
myFocusNode.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    if(myFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      myFocusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  });
});
```

Ps2: @Ravindra Kushwaha answer is better :)

Comment: Thank you!
This works as well, but just as @Ravindra Kushwaha's solution it has the problem that the keyboard immediately disappears again if I call `setState`... thanks for any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Alright, the keyboard problem was something different and is now solved as well: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20042 
Thanks for your help!